# Oracle - How to get number in varchar field with particular condition

Tags: oracle

I have this example table:

| ID | DESCRIPTION |
| --- | --- |
| AD112 | #21# |
| AD122 | #8970# |
| AD124 | NOT ALL SENT#115# |

what should i use to get exact number between '#', like this:

| ID | DESCRIPTION |
| --- | --- |
| AD112 | 21 |
| AD122 | 8970 |
| AD124 | 115 |

i've no clue to try code to, please help, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you said - between two # signs:

```
SQL> with test (id, description) as
  2    (select 'AD112', '#21#'               from dual union all
  3     select 'AD122', '#8970#'            from dual union all
  4     select 'AD124', 'NOT ALL SENT#115#' from dual
  5    )
  6  select id,
  7    substr(description, instr(description, '#', 1, 1) + 1,
  8                        instr(description, '#', 1, 2) - instr(description, '#', 1, 1) - 1
  9          ) description
 10  from test
 11  order by id;

ID    DESCRIPTION
----- -----------------
AD112 21
AD122 8970
AD124 115

SQL>
```